# Handling single quotes for inserting html into database

Tags: php

I have a bunch of html I want to put into a database field:

Sample:

```
<div id="match">
    <div class="match_image">
    <div class="thumbnail_block" style="float:none;width:70px;height:70px;">
<div class="thumbnail_image" style="width:68px;height:68px;">
    <a href="http://website.com/sweetangel000" onmouseover="javascript:startUserInfoTimer( 3512, $(this).find('.sys-online-offline:first') )" onmouseout="javascript:stopUserInfoTimer(3512)">
        <img src="http://website.com/templates/tmpl_dt_valkyrie_gold/images/spacer.gif" style="background-image:url(http://www.i-date-u.com/modules/boonex/avatar/data/images/3294.jpg);" width="64" height="64" alt="sweetangel000" title="sweetangel000" />
        <img src="http://website.com/templates/tmpl_dt_valkyrie_gold/images/icons/sys_status_offline.png" alt="Offline" title="Offline" class="sys-online-offline" onclick="showFloatUserInfo(3512, $(this)); return false;" width="12" height="12" />
    </a>
</div>
```

I want to sort of bypass the single quotes but addslashes() destroys the email that is sent later.

Is there another way to  do this?

Comment: Have you tried `mysql_real_escape_string` ?

Comment: addslashes do not destroys anything.

Comment: Yeah? You should see the email that's sent when I use it

Comment: But WHY do you send slashed data via email???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to run it through a sanitizing function (or use better yet, use parameterized queries). For MySQL, it's `mysql_real_escape_string`. This should be done for all user input, not just HTML, to prevent SQL injection.

Comment: You can't say "better yet", because "sanitizing" function is not an exact equivalent for the parameterizing. Escaping itself just not enough to make query data safe.

Comment: Something say about everyone comments but no answer huh?

Answer (score -2):

Have you tried  \" or \'

```
echo '<a href="' . $uri . '">' . $text . '</a>';
echo "<a href=\"$uri\">$text</a>";
```

Comment: What does this have to do with inserting into the database?

Comment: @ceejayoz - You can swap all single quote's using '\"' and that will help you avoiding the error.. shouldn't it?

Comment: He's not echoing, he's inserting into the database.

Comment: @ceejayoz yes ofcourse! but he will ultimately echo it for the email!